# Trying to display youtube hits on a wordpress pages using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, youtube, callback

This is my first post on the forum so go easy on me if I make a balls of it.

I'm using the Avada wordpress theme and I trying to use a callback on a specific page to the youtube api to display the hit counter of a youtube video.

I've included the jquery.js file in header.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

and then placed the following code in the html view on the wordpress page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var video_id='VA770wpLX-Q';

    $.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' + video_id + '?v=2&alt=jsonc',    function(data, status, xhr) {
        $('#targetId').text(data.data.viewCount);
    });
}); </script>

<p id="targetId"></p>
```

I can see the callback in the  console but  it wont display on the page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Stephen

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I added it to the header.php because it initial  didn't work on the page. I've removed it again I still having the same issue. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Everything works fine, but now you have to copies of jquery. One by default, and one you added manually.